# WhatsApp messages are not appearing in chronological order

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When in a group chat, if many messages are exchanged between other people in the group, when I check my Whatsapp, the messages are grouped according to sender and not chronologically. I know that my phone isn't the problem as I have recently changed my phone, however, I'm still experiencing the same problem.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing WhatsApp on my phone, and the same problem still occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I have seen many asking the same question in different places but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. So I decided to contact the WhatsApp team directly addressing the issue few days back. This is the response I received:

> WhatsApp Support
>
> Hi,
>
> Sorry for the delay! We have received many emails recently, and we do our best to answer them all. Thank you for your patience.
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience. We are aware of the issue, and we are doing our best to improve WhatsApp in a future update.
>
> Unfortunately, we cannot comment on any future timelines, sorry. Thank you for your continued patience and support of WhatsApp.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Tereza
>
> WhatsApp Support Team

Yea, they are working on it and it may be fixed soon.

Comment: The problem is still present, and reported, 5 years later. A contributing cause seems to be an intermittent internet connection. However, I religiously turn on airplane mode while driving and at night, so this is not an option for me.

Answer (score -1):

In  Settings, change your phone to use Automatic Date and Time.  I had the same problem, but doing this fixed it.